# Bioinformatics : Programmatic Access to the BacDive Database

Tags: python, database, html, bioinformatics

the resource at "BacDive" - ( http://bacdive.dsmz.de/) is a highly useful database for accessing bacterial knowledge, such as strain information, species information and parameters such as growth temperature optimums.

I have a scenario in which I have a set of organism names in a plain text file, and I would like to programmatically search them 1 by 1 against the Bacdive database (which doesnt allow a flat file to be downloaded) and retrieve the relevent information and populate my text file accordingly.

What are the main modules (such as beautifulsoups) that I would need to accomplish this? Is it straight forward? Is it allowed to programmatically access webpages ? Do I need permission?

A bacteria name would be "Pseudomonas putida" . Searching this would give 60 hits on bacdive. Clicking one of the hits, takes us to the specific page, where the line :     "Growth temperature:    [Ref.: #27]     Recommended growth temperature : 26 °C " is the most important.

The script would have to access bacdive (which i have tried accessing using requests, but I feel they do not allow programmatic access, I have asked the moderator about this, and they said I should register for their API first).

---

I now have the API access. This is the page (http://www.bacdive.dsmz.de/api/bacdive/). This may seem quite simple to people who do HTML scraping, but I am not sure what to do now that I have access to the API.

Comment: Can you please give us any names of bacteria (text in the flat file which you have to search) so that we can help. My suggestion is to use requests and lxml to extract data from the results. tell us exact requirement. Thanks

Comment: Please note that the access tag says "DO NOT USE this tag"

Comment: @Fionnuala , I have removed the "Access" tag.

Comment: @A.Chandu, I have edited and added an example of a bacteria.

Comment: Hi, i am successfull getting 60 results... now which link should i hit to get the info??

Comment: @A.Chandu theoretically if an organism search matches more than 1 hit, I would manually look at all 60 results, specifically the "growth temperature" line and take the HIGHEST number that I encountered. In this example, I just took the first record.

Comment: Okay i got it thanks..

Comment: @A.Chandu I think the API webpage is the only one we need, but I cant work out the structure in terms of how I would do a search for an organism using it. http://www.bacdive.dsmz.de/api/bacdive/).

Comment: Hi Added the solution to your problem. please let me know incase any issues. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution...

```
import re
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_growth_temp(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    no_hits = int(map(float, re.findall(r'[+-]?[0-9]+',str(soup.find_all("span", class_="searchresultlayerhits"))))[0])
    if no_hits > 1 :
        letters = soup.find_all("li", class_="searchresultrow1") + soup.find_all("li", class_="searchresultrow2")
    all_urls = []
    for i in letters:
        all_urls.append('http://bacdive.dsmz.de/index.php' + i.a["href"])
    max_temp = []
    for ind_url in all_urls:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(ind_url).read())
        a = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('Recommended growth temperature :'))
       if a:
           max_temp.append(int(map(float, re.findall(r'[+-]?[0-9]+', str(a)))[0]))
    print "Recommended growth temperature : %d °C:\t" % max(max_temp)

url = 'http://bacdive.dsmz.de/index.php?search=Pseudomonas+putida'

if __name__ == "__main__":
        # TO Open file then iterate thru the urls/bacterias 
        # with open('file.txt', 'rU') as f:
        #   for url in f:
        #      get_growth_temp(url)
     get_growth_temp(url)
```

### Edit:

Here I am passing single url. if you want to pass multiple urls to get their growth temperature. call the function(url) by opening file. code is commented.

Hope it helped you..
Thanks

Comment: Thats very well done, and very clear to follow. I like the use of regular expressions to fetch out the relevelant number data! I have substituted urllib for requests in my version. The specific bit that was stumping me was how to actually start the search with the organism, but that seems quite straight forward now that I see it. I am concerned about the speed of the script though. So much so, that I am considering only taking the first link and not sift through the remainder (i.e. the 61 hits). Do you think this is the fastest that the script will run, presumably because of internet based?

Comment: Only thing that affects the speed here is INTERNET  :) i worked on 1000's of urls so don't worry about it. I suggest you to go documentation 
Thanks

Comment: Thanks again Chandu!

Comment: After working with this script for a few hours today, I realised that we don't necessarily seem to be taking advantage of the API that bacdive themselves have offered, which presumably is required to boost the speed of data retrieval for their server, rather than pure web scraping. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: That's what... when there is API ... we can use them for effective work to be done :) 
Thanks

Comment: Okay... i will figure it out how to use that API with less number of lines of code. :) Get back to you .. Thanks

Comment: Hey Chandu, its really annoying because there isnt any real documentation on how to use the API, only a summary of the endpoints. I am new to this entire thing (i.e. web scraping and API). Because of your help, I have worked out the web scraping bit now, and I come to realise the power of beautiful soup and requests. I am sure, with your help I can learn how to use API's also! I am looking at youtube tutorials for other API's as I speak!

Comment: Hey @A.Chandu , i was taking a closer look at the API today, and realised that is supports HTML/JSON/XML formats.. the endpoints are clearly defined on the page. Do you think JSON or XML is better for speed?

Comment: In RestfulAPI's are make use of JSON. Also for better pythonic way JSON is good. :)

Comment: Hey Chandu, could you give me some example code on how to parse the json of a for example the "bacillus cereus " bacteria endpoint file?